# Main thread waiting

Tags: java, android

how can I make my process wait until the another process has completed by using "thread"
thx

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`join()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29)

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
     //some code
}
});

t.start();
t.join();//this will wait until Thread t completes its execution
```

Comment: I want that the application run when i open the browser.

Comment: This is different question , you can open new one with this requirement